# Confusion in definition of prime of a algebraic number field

Tags: number-theory, terminology, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading from *Algebraic Number Theory* by J. Neukirch on my own.

I am confused with the definition of prime divisors of a field extension.

This is on page page 44

[image]

Later in Chapter 3, he has defined it in some different way. 
[image]

Am I missing something ?  Are these definition equivalent?

Comment: The connection is that to each prime ideal we get a non-archimedean valuation. Different prime ideals lead to non-equivalent valuations, so this mapping is injective. The infinite places are something different, and correspond to different embeddings $K\to\Bbb{C}$. A field with $[K:\Bbb{Q}]<\infty$ has only finitely many infinite primes, so the prime ideals (infinitely many of those) kinda dominate the scene. But, the infinite primes are needed to get a comprehensive picture.

Comment: The quoted paragraph from page 44 causes the very kind of misunderstanding it seeks to prevent. The ring $\mathcal O_K$ has **prime ideals**, and it is imprecise to say that $K$ has the prime ideals of $\mathcal O_K$.

What Definition 1.1 defines are **primes** or **places**. It seems to me that he would have been better off giving the latter rather than the former as the primary term.

Answer (score 2):

From a linguistic perspective these are similar. This was a choice made by the developers of the theory because of (the natural generalization of) [Ostrowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem), namely that the absolute values of a number field, $K$, are all induced by prime ideals of $K$ and by the (non-equivalent) embeddings into $\Bbb C$. In the case of $\Bbb Q$ it is literally Ostrowski's theorem as each prime ideal is associated with a unique class of equivalent absolute values--the usual absolute value inherited from $\Bbb R$ is associated with the prime ideal $(0)$.

However, you're right these aren't literally the same thing, they are just connected (hence the linguistic similarity). If you look closely you'll see the first definition is for "prime **ideals**" and the second is for "primes."  While **we abuse the language** and use these things interchangeably in practice, **they are not literally the same thing**:

> One is a set satisfying some properties, the other is an equivalence class of functions satisfying some other properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked if "these definitions are equivalent", but I see only one definition in your snippets.

Prime ideals are a general concept in abstract algebra. They are defined for any (commutative) ring, of which the ring of integers is a special case.

The term defined in the second snippet, a **prime (of a number field)**, is a separate concept that is *a priori* unrelated to the more general definition of a prime ideal.

However, as one may guess, both concepts are somehow generalizing the concept of an (ordinary) prime number $p=2,3,5,\ldots$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But he says that "by prime of K" he means primes ideals of ring of integers .

Comment: No, he says the "prime ideals of K" are the prime ideals of the ring of integers. Note the presence of the word "ideal".

Comment: This is incorrect. A finite prime of a number field exactly corresponds to a prime ideal: given a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, we obtain the corresponding $\mathfrak p$-adic valuation; and given a non-Archimedean valuation, Ostrowski's theorem tells us it corresponds to a prime ideal. The two concepts are certainly related a priori. The point of introducing places is pretty much notational, since it allows the infinite and finite primes to be viewed in the same vein. I would think of a finite prime as being the same thing as a prime ideal.

Comment: @Mathmo123, your comment supports the point I have been trying to make: we need a (not particularly deep) theorem in order to establish a connection. This is an *a fortiori* reason that the two concepts are connected. I was trying to help someone who was learning the terms for the first time by pointing out that, as far as the definition goes, the terms are *a priori* unrelated. It is only by further considerations that the relationship between the concepts becomes clear.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157935/300