# Ramification of Archimedean primes

Tags: field-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K \subseteq L$ be an extension of number fields, let $v$ be an Archimedean place of $K$ and let $w$ be an Archimedean place of $L$ extending $v$. 
There are in practice three values that one usually assigns to the ramification index $e(w \mid v)$ and to the inertia degree $f(w \mid v)$:

- $e(w \mid v) := 2$ and $f(w \mid v) := 1$ in any case. This is what happens essentially when one excludes the Archimedean primes from a discussion, *e.g.* with sentences like "Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing all the Archimedean ones. Then for all $v \not\in S$...";
- $e(w \mid v) := 2$ and $f(w \mid v) := 1$ if and only if $v$ is real and $w$ is complex, otherwise $e(w \mid v) = f(w \mid v) = 1$. This is a "standard" choice in many textbooks, and comes from the fact that if $K \subseteq L$ is Galois then the decomposition group $D(w \mid v) := \{ \sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \, \colon w \circ \sigma = w \}$ is either trivial or cyclic of order two, and the latter happens if and only if $v$ is real and $w$ is complex (see [here](https://planetmath.org/RamificationOfArchimedeanPlaces));
- $e(w \mid v) := 1$ and $f(w \mid v) := 2$ if and only if $v$ is real and $w$ is complex, otherwise $e(w \mid v) = f(w \mid v) = 1$. This choice is made in the book "[Class field theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-11323-3)" by Gras (see [page 7](https://books.google.dk/books?id=UDTqCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=gras%20class%20field%20theory&hl=it&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false)), and allows us to talk about complex conjugation as the "Frobenius at infinity".
  Moreover, it agrees with the usual definition of the ramification index for non-Archimedean places, which is the index of the valuation groups. 
  The motivation is to simplify some of the notation in class field theory, *e.g.* to have $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ as the "standard" ray class fields of $\mathbb{Q}$ (without adding any ramification at $\infty$), and their totally real subfields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n + \zeta_n^{-1})$ as the ray class fields with extra conditions at $\infty$.

I have two questions concerning this:

1. Is there any uniform definition of $e$ and $f$ for an extension of valued fields, which would work also for Archimedean absolute values? The most difficult thing is of course to define $f$.
2. Do you have other reasons to prefer one of these definitions?

Comment: There is actually no "uniform" choice, because in the archimedean case, this is essentially a question of convention. The most common choice in ANT and CFT is your case 2. As for the choice of G. Gras and some of his followers, the motivation comes from the convenience in dealing with the prime 2. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157935/300700

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer in the linked question is very interesting, but it makes me wonder why the convention is essentially the one of Hasse. It seems that it brings only problems...

Comment: Do you mean that what I called the "most common" convention goes back to Hasse ? I learnt ANT and CFT in the books by Artin,Serre , Cassels-Fröhlich, etc. and never questioned their choice! The problems are with the prime 2, not with the convention. More precisely: in most cases, the prime 2 requires a specific proof, independently of any convention. It's only in the statements of the results that the Gras language is more convenient, in that it allows a unified language. Usually people get rid of the problem by decreeing that "p is odd".

Comment: The prime 2 is thus left to people in search of a thesis subject (I'm kidding). In Iwasawa theory, we often have to add to the base feld K all the p-primary roots of 1. The problem in the end is to "go down" to K, because for p=2, we are no longer in the so called "semi-simple" situation. That's why there is even a "proposition" asserting that "4 is a prime, not 2".